# How do I roll back a repository's commits as well as file changes, so that they don't show up in a pull request?

Tags: git, github

So I'm getting started with Git, and I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

I'm trying to roll back to a certain commit on my fork, erasing all history of commits and their changes back to that point. I've tried all the stuff I could find suggested around here, and it hasn't made a difference. I need to make a pull request to a project, but it's including ALL the commits I've made, as well as tons of merge commits. Everyone else that pulls to it don't have nearly as many commits as myself, so I believe I'm doing something wrong.

The only real reason I want to revert is because there's a WIP commit I made that I don't want included on the request, so I'd like to just start clean before that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to replay all commits and merges you made, just to remove one WIP commit. That's a lot of work and may be error prone, IMHO you could just revert that commit, with `git revert <sha>`

Comment: You shouldnt merge on a WIP branch you should instead rebase it.

Comment: Well it's not exactly that... It's more like, I was being dumb and trying a lot of commands and whatnot, in the process of getting back to this, and I'd really just like to start fresh. Part of doing this is so that I know how. (And don't worry, there's no one that will be using anything from my fork, so doing so won't create problems.) I'm needing to make a pull request eventually, to put some of my files back on, but there are several commits I no longer want on it, and I'd rather just roll back and merge in any updates from upstream, and then just put my changes back in later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git reset --hard` to go back as far as you need to, then commit, and finally push the new version up. (You'll need to use the `--force` flag when pushing to overwrite the remote branch.)

Try not to make a habit of doing this, though, since if someone had actually done something with the branch you pushed up, overwriting it would leave them with their own problems to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it has not worked for me. When I try to push (with the --force flag), it tells me that everything's up to date. I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: Huh. It must have been that... Because I just tried this from my other computer, and it worked just like you all said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard <commit_id>` will work to do what you want.  If you don't have shell access (i.e. it's a github repo or the like), you do the same thing on your client box and then `git push -f` to force the push.  Normally a push will fail if the current HEAD of the destination is not an ancestor of the new HEAD.

But if you do this, be very aware that anyone who cloned or pulled the old HEAD is going to be very confused: their future pulls will die with merge failures and they will hate you forever.  Rewriting history should always be a last resort.